# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView issue

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have an issue related to `recyclerView`. So I'm using it inside `NestedScrollView`. I know it's bad for the performance, but for now I don't have another solution.

I have pagination for my list and I gave the logic to `nestedScrollView`. So when it reaches to the bottom, I load the next list. When the time comes to update my list, I'm calling my adapter `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Look what's happening. I load 30 items for every pagination. When I load the first 30 items, I give them to my adapter and it binds all of them at once. That's ok because it's in `nestedScrollView`. When I scroll to the bottom and load the next 30 items, I'm calling `notifyDataSetChanged` for my adapter to update the UI. But this time instead of binding the next 30 items, it binds all the 60 items at once. And every time I load more and more items, it's getting worse, because it binds all the items in the adapter. Is there a way to prevent this and bind only the new added items?

Sorry I can't upload the code part. There's nothing special, it's a simple `recyclerview` inside `nestedScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is working fine it should load more and more on scroll. if you want the latest only then you can do one thing on the api function reinitialse your arraylist so it will bind the latest 30 only.

Answer (score 1):

A possibile solution could be using [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil). Once you have implemented your DiffCallback you can use it this way (taken from docs)

```
 List oldList = mAdapter.getData();
 DiffResult result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new MyCallback(oldList, newList));
 mAdapter.setData(newList);
 result.dispatchUpdatesTo(mAdapter);
```

I didn't actually try it but this way only updated items should be bound.

The problem you actually have is that, since your RecyclerView is inside a ScrollView, views are never actually recycled and this triggers the binding on all the items once you call notifyDataSetChanged.

**EDIT - Use ListAdapter**

I had a similar problem to solve recently, what I ended up doing is using the [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter) that simplifies the usage of DiffUtils.

```
class ItemsAdapter() :
    ListAdapter<Item, ItemViewHolder>(ItemComparator()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = 
        ItemViewHolder(parent)

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }
}

class ItemComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Item {
        return oldItem.prop1 == newItem.prop1 &&
                oldItem.prop2 == newItem.prop2 &&
                oldItem.prop3 == newItem.prop3
    }
}
```

In your Activity/Fragment simply call `adapter.submitList(items)` when you got the new page